# London Olympics Ticket Design - How to?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm in the process of designing a program invite and thought I could experiment something similar to the London Olympics ticket.

I am more interested in knowing how I can go about designing the blue shapes (polygons and triangles) part. Is it just different blue shapes  with gradients stacked against each other?
Are there any other effects to be added to get similar desired results?

[[image: London Ticket]

(larger version linked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVwNl.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up using with this little quick experiment:

[image: Silly picture of overlapping triangles.]

- Made some overlapping shapes on separate layers, with appropriate colors (Polygonal Lasso and Alt-Backspace)
- Adjusted Layer transparency
- Added Gradient Overlays, Drop Shadows, Outer Glows

It's useful to tweak the Blend mode in addition to Spread and Size for the glows. For gradients try different gradient styles (and angles + sizes), or if you know exactly what you want, use the Gradient Tool for best results.